# SharePoint 2013 Website Creation

Tags: 2013, public-website

In SharePoint 2015, how can I create a website that Domain users be able to log in to and see a page with such as tabs

Home/New/.../.../...

Under home they see some sub tabs as well.

I need some info regarding how to link a website to our local resources.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From central administration, you can create (or reuse an existing) a web application on create a new site collection using the Publishing Portal template.

By default, the navigation is "metadata managed" in SP2013 but you can easily roll back to the classic portal web based navigation (with sub sites to define your information architecture / hierarchy) by changing this in your navigation settings.

From the site collection, it will only be a matter of creating relevant sub-sites that are representing what you would like to achieve.